# Points of a centrally symmetric lattice polytope

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry

Let $P\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ be a centrally symmetric lattice polytope whose only interior lattice point is the zero vector. Is it true that $P$ is equivalent (up to ${\rm GL}(n,\mathbb Z)$ + lattice translations) to a lattice polytope contained in the cube of vertices $[\pm 1,\dots,\pm 1]$?